# Writing 100 rows form oracle database using powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I have an problem using powershell .
first i would like to explain what the sitiation is :

I have an Oracle database running with an table NAMES . In the table i got about 10000 rows with data . I would like to to count them til 100 rows and and then "echo " them on my powershell prompt here is where the problem comes in because i can count the rows using the following script:

```
  $query = “SELECT * FROM NAMES"
            $command = $con.CreateCommand()
            $command.CommandText = $query
            $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
           $test= $result|Measure-Object



$i=$test.Count
```

The number that returns is the correct number but then it goes wrong because when i want to use an foreach loop i cant get the names from my table

Here is wat i got maybey it helps

```
foreach ($Row in $query.Tables[0].Rows)
{ 
  write-host "value is : $($Row[0])"
}
```

hope someone finds an answer

Comment: Wouldn't you want to iterate over `$result` rather than `$query`?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [strict mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx): `Set-StrictMode -Version latest`. By setting it, you'd get much more informative an error message:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM NAMES"
foreach ($Row in $query.Tables[0].Rows) { ... }
Property 'Tables' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
+ foreach ($Row in $query.Tables[0].Rows) { ... }
```

The `$query` variable doesn't contain member `Tables`, so attempting to read it is futile. It would seem likely that the `$result` variable contains the `Tables` member. That depends on the data provider you are using and what's missing on the code sample.